# About "Android T-DMB " (How to get infomation about T-DMB)

Tags: android

our team planed making application with T-DMB(Terrestrial-Digital Multimedia Broadcasting) information in Android Smartphone.
but we can't found it.
most of Smartphone had T-DMB chip.
How to get data(signal power, raw data etc..) or information about T-DMB from Android Phone?
like T-DMB frequency scan...?

case of BLE, we can get some data.
UUID, major, minor.. and so on.

i wonder value about T-DMB & how to get it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "value" here? Are you looking for an API to access tv reciever chip in a phone?